# `std::lock_guard` for `std::counting_semaphore` and `std::binary_semaphore`

Tags: c++, locking, c++20, semaphore, raii

Is there any RAII guard similar to `std::lock_guard`, `std::scoped_lock` or `std::unique_lock` provided by the standard which I can use in combination with `std::binary_semaphore` and `std::counting_semaphore`?

Comment: Looks like at the moment there isn't ... maybe they'll add something like that in the next versions.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to a `std::mutex`, the acquire and release call of a `std::counting_semaphore` can happen on different threads. So, I think it is not the main use case of a semaphore to be locked and unlocked in the same scope. However, you can easily create your custom lock_guard like this:

```
#include <semaphore>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class custom_lock_guard
{
    T &m_;

public:
    custom_lock_guard(T &m) : m_(m)
    {
        m_.acquire();
        std::cout << "Lock acquired" << std::endl;
    }
    ~custom_lock_guard()
    {
        m_.release();
        std::cout << "Lock released" << std::endl;
    }
};

std::counting_semaphore<10> m(5);
std::binary_semaphore n(1);

int main()
{
    custom_lock_guard g(m);
    custom_lock_guard h(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wait until [std::experimental::scope_exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit) is supported.
Then you can write this:

```
{
  m.acquire();
  auto guard = std::scope_exit([&]{m.release();});
  // other stuff...
}
```

Until then you'll have to settle from a custom implementation.